# What are good routes to jungle and gank at level 2-3?

Tags: league-of-legends

What are possible **jungling routes** in LoL Season 5 to get to **level 2 and 3** (both possibilities) and **gank** afterwards? 
That is, jungle to get to those levels quickly and have enough health to gank afterwards (assuming you take the standard 2 pots you start with nowadays).
If it is necessary or optimal to **go back to base (?)** please say so, as well as when do you feel best to use the **smites**.
Interested in suggestions for **Panth** and **Amumu** (very different playstyles, which I have some experience with).

Comment: You can only take 2 potions and a Machete's actually, and it depends on which champion you want to take =)

Comment: hahaha my mistake, i was thinking of 500g instead of 475g, not the first time I make that mistake thx :D

Comment: Don't worry =)
However, which junglers are you referring to in the question?

Comment: Hmmm, you're right, it totally varies...
Well, I am pretty new to LoL but I have jungled with Amumu and Pantheon (and a bit of Jax to try, but forget him). Oh, and Kha'zix, which before getting my first Tier 3 runes I found too squishy but I might try again soon. Mainly interested in suggestions for Panth and Amumu (very different playstyles).

Comment: I have played pantheon and if you do golems red straight to blue you can gank you just need to time your w for the big creeps so that as they swing you hit them with w this stops them from attack mid swing which is better than stopping them after they swing do this for red and blue and you will be very healthy after you clear

Comment: Yes, I also try to time the W stun just before an attack!
So you're saying to do krugs (smite I suppose), Red and Blue? I will try that route, thanks! =)

Answer (score 4):

**When should you gank?**

You should Gank whenever you can create pressure without harming you nor your laners. If your laners are pushed it's harder to gank, but still doable, however you have to mind where the enemy jungler is to prevent him taking Dragon or counter ganking you.

**Ganking as Amumu on Top**

In my opinion, it's the easiest lane to gank before 6 and the hardest after 6. If the enemy toplaner is pushing to your turret you can easily come by the river and just jump in. Make sure the river isn't warded by smiting the Raptors (The camp near midlane).
If it's your own laner that is pushed, then it's a bit harder. Depending on how pushed and which side you're playing on, you can gank by the tri bush (If you're on the Blue side), but make sure your laner has CC as you're incredibly close to the turret, or just go from your own turret without giving vision of yourself and hide in the bush. Once the minion wave starts pushing so will the enemy laner and you can engage at that point.
If the lane is frozen at the middle a gank from the tribush is really good if they have no dashes, if they do, try to gank from the river instead.
After 6 you don't need to use your Q into the enemy champion, if you fear you might miss, aim for a minion near him and then use your ultimate to root him in place. Be careful however, since post 6 many top laners are either too safe or incredibly dangerous (Tryndamere, Teemo, Irelia, Riven are really difficult to gank)

**Ganking as Amumu on the midlane**
This can be very dangerous since most midlaners have a lot of escapes (especially Zed and Leblanc). This means your only choice is to wombo combo them. Don't really try to gank before 6 unless your teammate can stun him , the midlane is an easy place to run away from ganks. Like in the top lane, make sure you have either a sweeping lens or the raptor buff, and you can gank from anywhere except your own turret (unless you're sion or have TP and Homeguards). Preferably only gank when your laner managed to bait a fight, so that the enemy will not have his escapes up (most escapes are used to engage aswell). The exception to this is if it's a low mobility mage. If you see a Malzahar, Morgana, Lux and the like, by all means, dodge the snares and engage. They have no way to escape (Just beware of the damage, shield and slow respectively). Never ever dive a midlaner unless you're almost at full health. Especially not Malzahar / Lissandra / Anivia / Galio.

**Ganking as Amumu on Botlane**

Pre 6, unless the enemy is low, don't do it (unless your teammates have a lot of CC). You're slow. You have 1 stun. They usually will have 2 flashes an exhaust and a heal. The only thing you're doing is pushing your lane, and that isn't exactly the best thing to do. However if they are either low, out of mana or you can effectively lock them down, go ahead and try to kill one of them, maybe two if the second one is dumb enough to stay there. You can try the toplane trick here though, is your botlane pushed? Hide in the bush without the enemy noticing. Once the lane pushes back and they pass by you / facecheck the bush, that's a free stun for you, and possibly a kill if your team can follow up.
After 6, just run in there by the river, throw yourself at them and press R. Finish them off with your tears and if possible leave a kill for the adc

**Ganking as Pantheon**

Pantheon early game has everything that amumu has except a gapcloser. He does have a short gapcloser, which is his stun, but if the enemy is out of range you're screwed. Basicly the same principle applies here, run by the open gaps and try to combo. Q -> W -> E -> Q is the best combo for a gank, provided you have enough mana. If not, Q -> W -> Basic attack and Q again (You'll want your laner to be doing damage aswell , and save a Q to prevent the enemy from surviving at 10 hp, if your laner can't finish him off)
Post 6 your ganks are unbelievably easy. At this point you probabbly have boots (Extra points for Mobility Boots) and you can do the aforementioned rather easily. But you also have your ultimate.
Warn your team you're engaging, and where you're landing, and make sure they engage during your cast time. If the enemy backs he's gonna be crushed by your ultimate (You shouldn't ult into someone, but rather ult where they're going to be). If he doesn't back, it's still a 2v1 situation, and he took extra damage for keeping fighting (which will mean that you can kill him even easier). As Pantheon if you do take the Chilling Smite you can also slow an enemy which is incredibly useful (even if it doesn't seem so). Just don't smite while he's stunned, that's wasting your slow on someone that can't move.

**Routes**
Both of those junglers do need mana. As such your best start is

- Gromp (Smite) -> Blue -> Wolves -> Raptor (Smite) -> Base - > Red -> Gank Top / Gank Mid
  Alternatively
- Blue - > Wolves (Smite) -> Raptors - > Red (Smite) -> Gank Top/Mid

Those Are the best starts, however I wouldn't recommend the second one.
The first start allows you to reach level 3 in the best possible way. You get extra damage from the gromp and the ntake a blue buff. Take wolves for the experience. Once you take the Raptors not only you have vision denial but you'll reach level 3 (which allows you for your first decent combo). You go into base and buy the upgrade along with some pots. Do the red and gank. Use the potions to make sure you gank at high health.

The Second start is worse because you can't deny vision. Smiting the Blue Buff is a huge waste, so save your smite. You take the Blue and go to wolves. You probabbly won't be able to solo the Wolves so you'll have to smite them (if not save for raptors). Go straight to the raptors and clear them (And you'll hit level 3). Take the Red Buff and Smite it (It will heal you) and you gank a lane fairly high on health. However you might not have as much health as the first method, you're susceptible to be counterjungled at the red buff (Care for Rengar, Shaco and Warwick) and you won't have access to the Smite upgrades

Note: For the jungle routes you can also take the scuttle crab after finishing your initial clear for more health (If you have Lifesteal or Spellvamp), gold and vision. However, beware that the enemy jungler may have had the same idea.

Comment: Starting without blue will screw you completly on both those champions, hence why I didn't mention other routes as they're mostly unviable unless you're very experienced with your champions and will definently gank at level 2 (You need your laner to Provide extra cc which is rare at level 2)

Comment: Wow, incredibly detailed, thanks!!
I know about the mana hunger of my dear two friends, although I suffer it far more with Pantheon, as maybe I haven't learned not to spam my abilities and save mana yet...

Comment: You can easily clear with just the W which spends 8 mana per second, pantheon has to spam everything if he wants a fast clear =)

Answer (score 1):

I know this won't work with Pantheon/Amumu but other alternative routes might be helpful.  I do this on people like Rammus/Zac. Essentially champions without a heavy need for mana.

I start Gromp.  From here I will skip blue and do wolves.  After this you can do red and still have more health than normal after smiting it.  This lets you do a level 3 gank right away with plenty of health to spare.  (With Zac, I clear so fast that I do Gromp, Wolves, Chickens, and then Red)

This route obviously doesn't work well for Pantheon/Amumu since they are both so mana hungry, but it could be applied to a wider range of junglers than I mentioned as well as long as they meet the low mana criteria.

Comment: Low mana usage you mean =)

But yes, this is actually a good start for non mana users and non auto attackers (auto attackers get way more by starting Golems).

Although, it's not really where the OP is heading to :(

Comment: No no, I am interested =)
I am new and have just happened to be using mana hungry champions, but I am interested in trying other ones, and suggestions for Kha'zix for example I might even try soon!! This one does sound good. As they said above, smiting Raptors (chickens haha) does give you the vision denial, which early on when there aren't many wards could be useful, so... I'll consider everything =)

Comment: @DarJul I actually use the smite on red a lot in order to make sure I'm healthy.  That smite on that buff for the HP is extremely helpful.  I do smite the chickens a lot later, but first run not normally.  It makes the gank riskier.  A lot of people don't have good wards by then anyways.  If you can watch the map while you jungle, you can usually figure out where they put them.

Comment: yes, that seems like an option too, and the truth is I smite the red for the HP more often than not... =)
I have one more question as well @dphil !! I thought it was a good idea to **change to sweeping lens soon**, even after the first clear and back, to help gank, but I've also heard that it's not usual or beneficial for juglers to do so... What do you think of that? Reasons for doing or not doing it?

Comment: @DarJul I like to keep the warding trinket.  I'll usually use it to put deeper wards in the enemy jungle so that I know where they are.  I always upgrade it ASAP as well because it's essentially a mini sight stone.  I find that more beneficial in most cases than the red upgrade.  I figure between the pinks I get and the chicken smite I'm pretty good on clearing their wards.

Comment: However if you're a tank jungler (or lee sin) you do get more out of building a sighstone and then sweeping lens (clearing 1 ward every 90 seconds is beat by 2 or more =) )

Comment: why are lee sin/tank junglers more suited for sightstone?

Comment: @DarJul Lee Sin used to be good for sightstone since he could ward jump.  I would never build sightstone on him or other junglers anymore now.  I'd much rather just upgradet he ward trinket.  It's 550 less gold and it's almost as good without taking up an item slot.

Comment: @DarJul The reason though that tank junglers and lee sin can get it though, is that other junglers need the gold for items.  Tank junglers typically don't need as much gold to be useful to their team and so the sightstone burn isn't as bad.

Answer (score 1):

You win games by forcing enemies into paths they have only bad decisions and no counter or way to come back. Ganking at right time at right place is one way to archive that.

Typical low skilled jungle start looks like:

- Frog(Smite with lane help) + Blue + Wolves
- Frog(Smite with lane help) + Blue + Recall
- Frog(Smite with lane help) + Blue + River

Typical ways to mess with enemy jungle

- Take their Golem + Red or just Red.
- Kill them at wolves.
- Steal blue and possibly kill them.
- Do early dragon.

Answer (score 1):

Since pretty much everything has been said, remember that with some champs red buff can overall GIVE you health (shaco, warwick) because of smite bonus, so doing it while already damaged with said champs can help.

Also, the crab gives health and lots of XP so it's good too.

Comment: I've noticed after clearing a certain camp I get a bit of health without any apparent reason, no relation to smiting or jungle items that I know of either. Which monster is it? I don't know which one you refer with "the crab" haha, the Gromp (big purple toad)? The krugs (two grey turtle like things)? I got here in season 5 so maybe crab is what previous monsters were called... Thanks =)

Comment: @DarJul actually, all the large jungle monsters give health on kill, but the golems (krugs, yup) and gromp give more. cheers :)